# Xml Import to datagridview c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

Can you help me import this XML?

My difficulty is that he has no Elements.

Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<TBL>
  <CLI001>
    <NrCli>1000</NrCli>
    <Nome>Garagem Mira-Sintra, Lda.</Nome>
    <CPost>2710-011 SINTRA</CPost>
    <Comercial>7</Comercial>
    <VndNome>A. Tomás &amp; Lúcio- Terraplanagens e Cofragens, Lda</VndNome>
  </CLI001>
  <CLI002>
    <NrCli>1001</NrCli>
    <Nome>Auto Mecânica Torreense, Lda</Nome>
    <CPost>2560-231 TORRES VEDRAS</CPost>
    <Comercial>8</Comercial>
    <VndNome>Ricardo Rui Ribeiro - Sociedade de advogados</VndNome>
  </CLI002>
  <CLI003>
    <NrCli>1002</NrCli>
    <Nome>Auto Peças de Miranda, Lda</Nome>
    <CPost>5210-300 SÃO MARTINHO DE ANGUEIRA</CPost>
    <Comercial>10</Comercial>
    <VndNome>Jacinto Marques de Almeida Saraiva</VndNome>
  </CLI003>
<TBL>
```

Only the first record is import:

[image: Print Result]

```
try
{
  DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
  dataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\Rui\Desktop\myfilename.xml");
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

I can not see a way to get around this: s

Comment: Is it an invalid format error or something else? How do you expect people to help you without sharing the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

Then end Tag `<TBL>` should be closing tag `</TBL>`. Next time you can use [this](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0) URL to validate your xml.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there's a typo in your example xml, it should have a closing  tag. I'm assuming that your actual XML has the closing  tag, since your code would have failed when it tried to load the XML into the DataSet.

The reason that you're only seeing one row in your datagridview is because there *is* only one row in dataset.Tables[0]. Each of your CLI tags (CLI001, CLI002, CLI003) are loaded as seperate tables into your dataset. Look at the structure of the data loaded in your datagrid view, it conforms to the child items of CLI001. If you want to display all of them in a single DataGridView, you will need to merge them into a single datatable.

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\Rui\Desktop\myfilename.xml");

//merge all the tables into a single one
var dtMerged = dataSet.Tables[0].Copy();

for (int i = 1; i < dataSet.Tables.Count; i++)
{
    dtMerged.Merge(dataSet.Tables[i]);
}

//set the datasource using the merged datatable
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtMerged;
```

Comment: @rui glad I could help. Can you mark the answer as correct?